ogr2ogr not available with 'pixi global install gdal'
I'm trying to use prefix.dev's pixi package manager to install GDAL as a "globally" available package, similar to what you'd get by using a conda/mamba environment. Pixi still uses conda-forge as an available channel so I thought this would work.
I'm only able to use ogr2ogr from the command if I create a local project and add gdal as a dependency.
pixi init projectname # Creates the project folder
cd projectname # Go into the project
pixi add gdal # Add GDAL as a dependency
pixi shell # Invoke pixi shell and now you can run ogr2ogr

Attempting to install GDAL as a global tool:
pixi global install gdal
✔ Installed package gdal 3.9.2 py312h16ac12d_4 from conda-forge
  These executables are now globally available:
   -  gdal2tiles-script.bat
   -  gdal2tiles.bat
   -  gdal2tiles.bat
   -  gdal2xyz-script.bat
   -  gdal2xyz.bat
   -  gdal2xyz.bat
   -  gdal_calc-script.bat
   -  gdal_calc.bat
   -  gdal_calc.bat
   -  gdal_edit-script.bat
   -  gdal_edit.bat
   -  gdal_edit.bat
   -  gdal_fillnodata-script.bat
   -  gdal_fillnodata.bat
   -  gdal_fillnodata.bat
   -  gdal_merge-script.bat
   -  gdal_merge.bat
   -  gdal_merge.bat
   -  gdal_pansharpen-script.bat
   -  gdal_pansharpen.bat
   -  gdal_pansharpen.bat
   -  gdal_polygonize-script.bat
   -  gdal_polygonize.bat
   -  gdal_polygonize.bat
   -  gdal_proximity-script.bat
   -  gdal_proximity.bat
   -  gdal_proximity.bat
   -  gdal_retile-script.bat
   -  gdal_retile.bat
   -  gdal_retile.bat
   -  gdal_sieve-script.bat
   -  gdal_sieve.bat
   -  gdal_sieve.bat
   -  gdalattachpct-script.bat
   -  gdalattachpct.bat
   -  gdalattachpct.bat
   -  gdalcompare-script.bat
   -  gdalcompare.bat
   -  gdalcompare.bat
   -  gdalmove-script.bat
   -  gdalmove.bat
   -  gdalmove.bat
   -  ogr_layer_algebra-script.bat
   -  ogr_layer_algebra.bat
   -  ogr_layer_algebra.bat
   -  ogrmerge-script.bat
   -  ogrmerge.bat
   -  ogrmerge.bat
   -  pct2rgb-script.bat
   -  pct2rgb.bat
   -  pct2rgb.bat
   -  rgb2pct-script.bat
   -  rgb2pct.bat
   -  rgb2pct.bat

I do have a good bit of GDAL's functionality available now without having to activate the shell, but no ogr2ogr.

I don't know anything about pixi, had never heard of it until now. But all those global executables listed are batch files that call gdal python utilities. None of the binary executables eg gdal_translate gdalwarp ogr2ogr ogrinfo etc, are listed. Maybe do a search of your filesystem for ogr2ogr.exe and see if it actually did get installed somewhere.

I just installed pixi, ran pixi global install gdal and ogr2ogr was installed to .pixi/envs/gdal/bin.  Same folder as the wrapper shell scripts for the gdal python utilities.  Perhaps its a bug that the executable binaries don't get shown as installed and the wrapper scripts do.

That is rather interesting, so you were able to use ogr2ogr from the command line after the global install? What platform are you on?

I haven't tried to use it apart from running full/path/to/ogr2ogr --help which worked. Linux, but Windows is likely to be the same, i.e look in the $Env:PIXI_HOME\envs\gdal\bin directory (default PIXI_HOME is $Env:USERPROFILE\.pixi, i.e. C:\Users\YOU.pixi).

TL;DR -  you should install both GDAL and libgdal with pixi global install gdal libgdal-core.
Installing gdal with Pixi only installs the Python-based GDAL commands. To install the others - including ogr2ogr, gdalinfo, and gdaltranslate - you also need to install libgdal.
For older versions of gdal, you should run pixi global install libgdal. However, the latest versions of libgdal (3.9 onwards) are in a different package called libgdal-core. So if you want the latest version, you should install libgdal-core alongside gdal.

Nope, turns out I was wrong. pixi global install gdal libgdal-core successfully installed all of the tools I was looking for Thank you for the help!
